# Why google.maps.Geocoder and Google Geocoding API return different results?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Google maps API V3 offers two ways to convert an address to a LatLng: google.maps.Geocoder class and Google Geocoding API. While I found that the two methods return different results when I tried to get the LatLng of the same address. And google.maps.Geocoder is more accurate as I have found. Why is that?

I need to make an application to get the LatLng of a list of addresses so the google.maps.Geocoder cannot help on this but the Google Geocoding API is not so accurate. Any ideas?

For example:

On the picture below, the red icon is the result of google.maps.Geocoder and the blue one is the result of Google Geocoding API. They are both from the address: "1 Xinjiekou North Street, Beijing, China"

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: As far as I knew they were the same, I think the geocoder isn't a standalone service, if you look at the API http://**maps**.googleapis.com/**maps**/api/geocode/output?parameters it's still beolinging to the googlemaps API actually, You should share some code so we can examine it and find possible things that made the result change, maybe accesing from the API directly uses some different default values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both return the same coordinates for me:

http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1%20Xinjiekou%20North%20Street,%20Beijing,%20China&geocode=1

Xinjiekou 1st Alley, Xicheng, Beijing, China, 100035 (39.9416447, 116.37176850000003)

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1%20Xinjiekou%20North%20Street,%20Beijing,%20China&sensor=false

```
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 39.9416447,
           "lng" : 116.3717685
        },
```

Comment: Thank you. But how is geocodezip working? How do you get the coordinates?

Comment: [That](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=1%20Xinjiekou%20North%20Street,%20Beijing,%20China&geocode=1) uses the Google Maps Javascript API v3 geocoder.

Comment: It's my carelessness. I got the wrong coordinates, which is the north east of the viewpoint. lol.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `lat` and `lng` of `geometry.location` will be rounded to a precision of 7 by the Geocoding-API.

Comment: That doesn't explain the difference shown in the map.  A 7 digit floating point number is accurate to approximately 0.1 meters (~110.5km/degree at the equator).  The distance shown is larger than that.